# How to parse through JSON data from URL in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to loop through a JSON dictionary which is retrieved from POSTing to a URL. After retrieving the data and serializing it as a JSON object, I am unable to access the individual parts of the data.

```
func retrieveLotStatus(lotNumber: String) {
    let allowedChars = (CharacterSet(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#-[] ").inverted)

    var url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "fakeURLHere")!)
    let BodyData = "lotNum=" + lotNumber + "&field=" + PHASE.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedChars)!
    url.httpMethod = "POST"
    url.httpBody = BodyData.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No Data")
            return
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        print(responseJSON)
        if let jsonData = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            if let ItemNumber = jsonData["ItemNumber"] as? [String: Any] {
                print(ItemNumber)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This is an example of what JSON data is being retrieved when printing the response for reference

```
    Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x17d08c90>(
{
    Count = 4;
    ItemNumber = 1;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 4;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 10;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 10a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 11;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 11a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 4;
    ItemNumber = 1a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 4;
},
{
    Count = 2;
    ItemNumber = 2;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 2;
},
{
    Count = 2;
    ItemNumber = 2a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 2;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 3;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 3a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 4;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 4a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 5;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 5a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 6;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 6a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 7;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 7a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 8;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 8a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 9;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
},
{
    Count = 1;
    ItemNumber = 9a;
    PercentComplete = "100.00";
    Total = 1;
}
)
)
```

I am trying to loop through each object and append the value to a table. However before I can get to formatting them as UITableCell, I am trying to simply read each responseJSON["ItemNumber"], responseJSON["Count"], responseJSON["Total"] and responseJSON["PercentComplete"]

Comment: `responseData` is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to cast an array of dictionaries to a dictionary.

```
if let jsonData = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [[String:Any]] {
    for item in jsonData {
        if let itemNumber = item["ItemNumber"] as? Int, let count = item["Count"] as? Int, let percentComplete = item["PercentComplete"] as? Double, let total = item["Total"] as? Int {
            //use data
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you follow the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelcase for variables.

Comment: Thank you David, this helped greatly